# Magento - Too many connections

Tags: mysql, magento, connection

I am getting `Too many connections` error from Magento. 
I have increased the `max_connection` to 1000 but I am still getting the error. 
I contacted hosting provider and they asked me to use command `show processlist;` and review my coding.

When I ran the command, I only saw few active connections (about 4 to 5 connection). Therefore, I have no clue how to fix the problem.

I have increased the max_connection to 1500 and I am getting `create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug` error now.

Could anyone can help me with this situation please?
I am grateful for your help and time.

This is my my.cnf

```
key_buffer = 384M

max_allowed_packet = 1M

table_cache = 1024

sort_buffer_size = 2M

read_buffer_size = 2M

read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M

thread_cache_size = 16

query_cache_type = 1

query_cache_size = 48M

log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysqld.slowquery.log

max_connections=1000

wait_timeout=120

tmp_table_size = 64M

max_heap_table_size = 64M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M

open_files_limit=34484
```

#

And this is show proccesslist

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
| Id    | User      | Host      | db                 | Command        | Time  | State              | Info             |

+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------+--------------------+------------------+

|  4729 | root      | localhost | abc_def| Sleep          | 13093 |                    | NULL             |

| 16282 | eximstats | localhost | eximstats          | Sleep          |    84 |                    | NULL             |

| 16283 | DELAYED   | localhost | eximstats          | Delayed insert |    84 | Waiting for INSERT |                  |

| 16343 | root      | localhost | NULL               | Query          |     0 | NULL               | show processlist |

+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion not worth of a real answer — switch to a Magento aware host like Nexcess.  Magento's performance profile falls outside the normal bounds of a standard shared hosting provider's server setup.

Comment: May be your server is not capable to run the Magento. So Just go with dedicated server with good configurations ..

Answer (score 0):

You can increase max connections, but just so much

In essence there are too many connections being started, or not closed

So you can

1. increase max connections to allow more connections being started
2. Reduce `wait_timeout` for the connections that have gone away to free up again
3. Investigate where all these connections request are coming from? (can often be bots, or may bots at once, some index update or other cronjob etc)

thanks, hope it helps